# How to set the width of a survey-form?

Tags: 2007, survey-list

Hallo,

if a survey in sharepoint 2007 is taken, the form containing the question and the answers is fixed and i need to customize this width. I've created a custom master page and tried to fiddle with the CSS, but the form resists all my efforts to change its width. The colors and text-sizes, etc. are displayed as specified in the CSS, but setting the 'width' in the CSS does not have an effect at all.

Background: i need the survey to use the whole screen-estate so the survey can be taken using a touch-screen display.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems the ListFormWebPart is some kind of monster.
I tried to set the width using various ways in CSS - without any effect.
Then i opened the SharePoint Designer, set the width in the properties of the ListFormWebPart,
and that's all it took!

P.S.: There's nothing like answering your own question ..

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the page using Firebug, it looks like the only thing constraining the width is the "ListForm" table:

```
#onetIDListForm { width: 100%; }
```

I also had a question with a rating, which wasn't expanding so I updated it to this:

```
#onetIDListForm, .ms-formbodysurvey table { width: 100%; }
```